# drop down menu height adjust with scroll bar issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I loaded drop down using my dynamic data. all are working well. but problem is drop down height, and scroll. when I click it I appear in the top. I need to define height and scroll it. how i do it ?

Please check this image
[image: view]

Html

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedYear" ng-options="label for label in Years" ng-change="UpdateNumberOfDays()">
        <option value="">--Year--</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select onfocus='this.size=10;' 
onblur='this.size=1;' 
onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'></select>
```

Try This.

Comment: I tired this solution. but dropdown comes from position relatively, layout drag.